# How to accept any multipart file (image/pdf/csv) from postman and create the same file into SFTP location in Mule 4?

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, mule4

When I tried this usecase for some MIME types the content is coming in payload.parts[0].content, for some MIME types the content is coming in payload.parts.file.content. How to create the file in the same MIME type as how we received from postman in SFTP?

Comment: What `MIME types` you have tried with different expression. Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite not sure in what ways you have used and tested the both expression. Please find the screenshot below. I have added different format of datas in single request.  If you use mutiple format in single request and wanting to extract individually.  Use `payload.parts[0].content` and `payload.parts[1].content`

Note: This expression ideally mean whatever you add (form-data) in postman body request can be extract using index.
Example: if you have added content-type: application/xml in the below picture 3rd row, should be using `payload.parts[2].content`

If you're using single request `payload.parts.file.content` can be used.

Once after the request reached `HTTP/HTTPS` ( source listener), use dataweave as below to convert binary in to the defined structure data

```
%dw 2.0
output multipart/form-data
---
payload
```

After extracting the contents using the expressions, you can write in to SFTP (Screenshot) here I have stored in `Vars` (based on your logic)

[image]

[image]